# Why is my node always a few milestones behind

Tags: milestones, botbox

I run headless full node. I am synced, latestMilestone == latestSolidSubtangleMilestone. But my latestMilestoneIndex is always a few (3-10) behind from the most recent milestone in the Botbox channel. Why? I thought in order to be truly synced, I had to be caught up with the most current milestone

Comment: Check your neighbors what milestone index they have. If they all are lagged that way behind too, they should probably investigate why they are 3-10 minutes behind. Or try to find a neighbor that is more synced than your current neighbors.